# Constructing a function that is discontinuous at each rational point in an interval

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Construct a monotone function which has countably many discontinuities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69317/construct-a-monotone-function-which-has-countably-many-discontinuities)

How would I construct a monotone function on $[0,1]$ that is discontinuous at each rational point.

Comment: One rational at a time?

Comment: I think titi is looking for a monotone function $f$ such that the set of points of continuity of $f$ is $[0,1] \setminus\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @mixedmath: I don't understand what you mean by one rational at a time.

Comment: @leo: That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Take $r:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$. I think the function $$f(x)=\sum_{r(k)\lt x}2^{-k}$$ is a example. This function was discussed here before but I can't find the post.

Comment: Just clarifying, I mean $$f(x)=\sum_{k:r(k)\lt x} 2^{-k}$$

Comment: Finally found, actually exact duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/69317/8271

Comment: @leo: Thanks for the link. I'd appreciate it though if you or anyone could explain to me why the function is not right continuous.

Comment: ok, consider $x$ rational in $[0,1]$. Then $x+1/n\to x$ and  note that $$f(x+1/n)\to \sum_{k:r(k)\leq x}2^{-k}\neq f(x)$$

Comment: @leo: Thanks....