# Set of discontinuities of a function that has both limits at each point of $R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ has both a left limit and a right limit at each point of $\mathbb R.$ Then the number of discontinuities of $f$ is what $?$

Now the **G**reatest **I**nteger **F**unction is one such function and has countable infinite discontinuities.

Any continuous function  also has both limits at each point and they are same and number of discontinuity is $0.$

So , is there  a function with both limits at each point that has number of discontinuities uncountable $?$ Is that possible $?$

Comment: Please see the accepted answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275122/can-we-construct-a-function-that-has-uncountable-many-jump-discontinuities)

Answer (score 1):

The number of discontinuities of such an $f $ is at most countable. Indeed, since the lateral limits always exist, every discontinuity is a jump one; [and the number of jump discontinuities is at most countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1378513/22857).