# Discontinuity properties of $f_n$ carries over to the limit function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

> Suppose that $f_n:[a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Which of the following discontinuity properties of the functions $f_n$ carries over to the limit function ?
>
> - No discontinuities
> - At most ten discontinuities
> - At least ten discontinuities
> - Uncountably many discontinuities
> - Countably many discontinuities
> - No jump discontinuities
> - No oscillating discontinuities

---

**My try :**

**For first bullet:** If each $f_n$ is continuous and convergence is uniform, then by $\varepsilon/3$ argument, $f$ is continuous, which means $f$ has no discontinuities.

**For fourth bullet:** To disprove this , consider $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & \text{if}\; x \in  \Bbb Q \cap [0,1]\\\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then $f_n$ is discontinuous everywhere on $[0,1]$ whereas the limit $f=0$ is continuous. Of course , the convergence is uniform

**For fifth bullet:** To disprove this, consider $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & \text{if}\; 0<x<\frac{1}{n}  \\\\0 &\text{if}\;x=0 \wedge \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1\end{cases}$$

Here $f_n$  converges uniformly to $f=0$ and each $f_n$ has discontinuous at $x=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{n}$ but $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$.

This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666851/jump-discontinuities-under-uniform-convergence) answers the sixth bullet

---

Is my arguments correct ?  Can I have a hint for others ?

Comment: My reading of the fifth one is that "countably" means the set of discontinuities is either empty, finite, or countably infinite.

Comment: The first bullet point is *exactly* about the case where $f_n$ has no discontinuities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First bullet point is correct.

Hint for second: This property also propagates from the $f_n$ to $f$. The proof is similar to the proof for the first bullet point: If $f$ has a discontinuity at some $x_0$, then the $f_n$ must also have a discontinuity at $x_0$ for all $n>N$ for some suitable $N$.

Hint for third: Very similar construction to the 4th, which is correct.

Fifth bullet point is incorrect, as remarked by zhw. Your construction shows a  limit $f$ that does have countably many discontinuities (namely $0$). For a hint, prove and then use that if all $f_n$ are continuous at some point $x_0$, $f$ is also continuous at $x_0$.

To do that, consider such a point $x_0$ and a given $\epsilon > 0$. We know that because of the uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$, there is a $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$$ \forall x \in [a,b], \forall n > N: |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac {\epsilon}3$$

We also know that $f_{N+1}$ is continuous at $x_0$, which means

$$ \exists \delta > 0: |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f_{N+1}(x) - f_{N+1} (x_0)| < \frac {\epsilon}3$$

Together this means

$$ |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_0)| = |f(x) - f_{N+1}(x) + f_{N+1}(x) - f_{N+1}(x_0)+ f_{N+1}(x_0) -f(x_0)| \le |f(x) - f_{N+1}(x)| + |f_{N+1}(x) - f_{N+1}(x_0)| + |f_{N+1}(x_0) -f(x_0)|< \frac {\epsilon}3 + \frac {\epsilon}3 + \frac {\epsilon}3 < \epsilon$$

In a nutshell, this is the proof that uniform convergence of a function sequence of continuous functions implies continuity of the limit.

For the 7th point I'd like to have an exact definition of an oscillation discontinuity. Just as with the proof that non-jump discontinuities can form a jump discontinuity in the limit, by basically masking the jump discontinuity in the $f_n$ by adding a smaller and smaller oscillation, it may be possible to do the same here, depending on the exact definition.

Comment: Any chance you could expand on your hint for the fifth bullet point (countably many discontinuities)? I'm having a lot of trouble seeing where an argument could go from there.

Comment: Let $f_n(x): [0,1] \to \mathbb R, f_n(x)=\frac1n$ when $x=\frac1m$ for some $m=1,2,\ldots$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise.

This converges uniformly to the constant zero function, but $f_n$ has countably many discontinuities (at $0$ and $\frac1m$ for $m=1,2,\ldots$).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I was hoping that you could expand on how "if all $f_n$ are continuous at some point $x_0$, $f$ is also continuous at $x_0$" implies that the property of having at most countably many discontinuities is inherited by the limit function under the assumption of uniform convergence. Thanks for your response, though, I really appreciate your contributions to the online math community!

Comment: I added the proof, I hope it's understandable

Comment: Thanks again for your generous help. Your proof was clean and easy to follow. That being said, it's not the uniform limit theorem I've been having trouble with. What I haven't been able to see is how this theorem can be applied as you have said it can to answer the question posed by the original poster in their fifth bullet point. If you have the time to illuminate me in that regard I would be very grateful.

Comment: Since the sequence $f_n$ contains countably many functions, and since each of them has countably many discontinuities, the set of points where any of the $f_n$ is discontinuous is countable as well. My remark means that those are the **only points** that could be discontnuities of $f$, as for all the other points , where **all** the $f_n$ are continuous, $f$ must be continuous as well. That uses "countable" in the sense of "finitely or infinitely" countable. It does not prove that '**infinitely** countable discontinuities must stay infinite in the limit, but they can't become uncountable many.