# Example of an increasing, integrable function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ which is discontinuous at all rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, examples-counterexamples

I have really no idea about this:

> **Problem**: Show that there exists a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that:
>
> 1. $f$ is discontinuous in all $x\in \mathbb Q$.
> 2. $f$ is increasing in $[0,1]$.
> 3. $f$ is integrable.

**EDIT**: Sorry, it is not discontinuous in all $x\in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$, just in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I think that $1$ and $3$ contradict itself, since if $f$ is almost everywhere not continuous it is not integrable

Comment: @Belgi: that depends on your measure...

Comment: @Belgi The indicator function of the rationals is not continuous anywhere, but is integrable on any measurable set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general for any countable set $C \subset \mathbb R$ you can find a monotone function that is discontinuous only on $C$. Your particular case has already been answered elsewhere on the site, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69321/1930) answer of Brian Scott.

Comment: You found it quicker than I did!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I used google ;).

Comment: I usually do too, but I couldn’t remember a good set of search terms for that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can take $f_0(x)=x$ and a surjective map $q:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, then take:
$$ I_x^N = \{n\in\mathbb{N}:q(n)\leq x\}, $$
$$ f_N(x) = f_0(x)+\sum_{n\in I_x^N}\frac{1}{n^2+1}, $$
$$ f(x) = \sup_{N}\, f_N(x). $$