# Prove that there exists a monotone nondecreasing function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ discontinuous in rationals

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there exists a monotone nondecreasing function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ discontinuous in rationals of $[0,1]$

- I tried to test functions of the type 
  $$ f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{q} & \text{if } x=\frac{p}{q} \mid p,q \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, \gcd(p,q)=1  \\ x & \text{if } x \not\in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
  which is discontinuous in all rationals, but is not monotone.

Comment: possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296195/example-of-an-increasing-integrable-function-f0-1-to-mathbbr-which-is-di?rq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69317/construct-a-monotone-function-which-has-countably-many-discontinuities/69321#69321

Answer (score 10):

Since $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is countably infinite, then there's a bijection:
$$\phi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$$

Now define
$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\sum_{\phi(n)\leq x}2^{-n}$$

Since the geometric series is absolutely convergent, thus rearranging terms does not change the sum, so $f$ is well defined. Clearly $f$ is non decreasing, and
$$\lim_{x\to \phi(n)^-}f(x)=\sum_{\phi(k)<\phi(n)}2^{-n}<f(\phi(n))$$

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 I am also curious about other examples. Will you be interested in sharing yours?

Comment: Yup,working on it now,don't type quick in Jax. Still not good at it.

Comment: I'm considering deleting the example since for some reason,people didn't approve. IS it wrong? Someone give me a constructive critique and not just downvote it-if it's legitimately in error,I want to know and why. If not,stop downvoting out of spite.