# Give an example of function that satisfies this theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, examples-counterexamples, monotone-functions

Give an example  of function that satisfies this theorem ?

Theorem :The  set  of  points  of  discontinuity  of  a monotonic function   $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is  at most countable

My attempt :  i take   $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \ \text{ if x} \in  \mathbb{Q} \\ 0  \ \text{if  x} \in  \mathbb{Q^c} \end{cases}$

Is its true ?

Comment: If it is a theorem then wouldn't any monotonic function work?

Comment: $f$ is not even monotonic.

Comment: To find an example seems too trivial.  You could take $f(x)=x$, or $g(x)=e^x$.  Pretty much any continuous monotonic function satisfies this theorem

Comment: @NazimJ $ f(x) = x$   has no   discontniuity. How  can u take that

Comment: A good example is $ f(x)=x^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$

Comment: Because the set of points of discontinuity of a continuous function is the empty set.  Which has size 0.  This satisfies the condition "at most countable"

Comment: @jasmine The empty set is (at most) countable.

Comment: @Servaes thanks u

Comment: @NazimJ thanks  u i gots it now

Comment: I think an interesting example would be to find a monotone function with countably many discontinuities. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69317/72031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not correct. The function $f$ is discontinuous at **every** point of $\mathbb R$, besides, of course, *not* being monotonic.

An example would be $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$.