# A proof about the discontinuities on the principles of mathematics analysis

Tags: continuity

[image]
[image]

As the verification is left to the reader, I try to verify it and it seems it is somehow natural: when $x_n$ is a point of $E$, when $x\ge x_n$, the $c_n$ is added, while when $x_n$ is not a point of $E$, as the series is convergent, by Cauchy theorem the gap between the $x\le x_n$ and the $x\ge x_n$ can be arbitrary small.

But I found when I change this idea to the strict proof, I can reach it. Could you write down the strict proof? Thank you.

EDIT: Thanks for the comment. Now I understand how to write strictly for proving the discontinuous point, but I still can not write it down in the epsilon-delta language when proving continuous. I think the reason that I can not write it in epsilon-delta language is that (just suppose the $E$ is rational numbers in $(a,b)$ or some other countable but not finite set), for each rational number though I can enumerate and number it I still can not no what definite number in a enumeration it belongs to.

Comment: See if [this specific example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69317/construct-a-monotone-function-which-has-countably-many-discontinuities/69321#69321) helps.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you! Could you write the proof of the continuous point (on your specific example) in a more strict epsilon-delta language?

Comment: Let $a\in[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ and $\epsilon>0$. For $x\in[0,1]$ let $L(x)=\{n\in\Bbb N:q_n<x\}$. If $x<a$, then $$f(a)-f(x)=\sum_{n\in L(a)\setminus L(x)}2^{-n}\;.$$ Given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $2^{-m}<\epsilon$, and there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$(a-\delta,a)\cap\{q_n:n\le m\}=\varnothing\;.$$ Then for $x\in(a-\delta,a)$ we have $$f(a)-f(x)=\sum_{n\in L(a)\setminus L(x)}2^{-n}\le\sum_{n>m}2^{-n}=2^{-m}<\epsilon\;.$$ You can make a similar argument for $x>a$. (Sorry to have taken so long: I just plain forgot about this.)